# Multi-layer geom_bar shade legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, geom-bar, stacked-bar-chart

I have a very trivial question but for some reason I cannot figure out a solution to this...

Essentially, I have a *stacked* `geom_bar` plot where I'm looking at insertions and deletions for four different samples. I'm also comparing two different approaches, the second of which provides higher detection values for both variables.

I'm able to generate a plot which shows in the legend different color for the different variables; however, I wish to add a "shade" legend indicating the two different approaches used: **reference** in darker shade and **graph** in lighter shade, respectively.

Is there an easy way to do so without having to resort to faceting? (I'm trying to keep the plot as simple as possible). Thanks in advance! *See below* for an example. [![enter image description here][1]][1] And `code`.

```
library(grid)
library(ggh4x)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggdark)
library(ggpubr)
library(gtable)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)
library(reshape2)
library(ggchicklet) #round column
library(RColorBrewer)

excel_variants <- read_excel("/path/to/.xlsx")

df_variants <- data.frame(excel_variants)

df_variants$sample <- factor(df_variants$sample, levels=c('HG002', '6103671', '6103673', '6103675'))
df_variants$variant_type <- factor(df_variants$variant_type, levels=c('INS', 'DEL'))
df_variants$approach <- factor(df_variants$approach, levels=c('reference', 'graph'))

### PLOT THE DATA
plot <- 
  ggplot(df_variants, aes(x=sample, y=count, fill=variant_type)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge', color='black', width=.3, alpha=.6) + scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(12, "Paired")[c(7, 8)]) + theme_bw() +
  
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5), legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom', legend.direction='horizontal') + 
  ggtitle("INDELs gain") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title='variant type', title.position='top', title.hjust=.5))
plot

ggsave(filename = "variants.png", width=6.5, height=5)
```

Comment: You might look at the `biscale` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biscale/vignettes/biscale.html

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring, I tried to play around with `biscale` but didn't reallt do what I wanted to... in the meantime, I figured out a hack, however, the code is not very elegant... if anyone has a better solution is welcome to propose!

Comment: @Matteo You should post your hack as an answer to your question. It might help others or inspire a more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks @divibisan I will; I wasn't aware that would have push for answers from the community. I was looking around and many ppl seem to be using some sort fo "dirty&quick" code for this or similar issues, but I would be very happy to know the proper way to do it!

Comment: (btw, it's best practice if your question can include example data as code so that we can run it straightaway to try possible solutions. It's also nice if you can exclude packages that aren't used in the code or aren't related to the main question.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a possible solution, though the code is not very elegant, and I ended up plotting a new bar chart with corresponding scale (`ggnewscale`), then set the count on the

y-axis to zero. *See below* [image]

And `code`

```
library(grid)
library(ggh4x)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggdark)
library(ggpubr)
library(gtable)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(forcats)
library(reshape2)
library(ggchicklet) #round column
library(ggnewscale)
library(RColorBrewer)

excel_variants <- read_excel("/path/to/.xlsx")

df_variants <- data.frame(excel_variants)

df_variants$sample <- factor(df_variants$sample, levels=c('HG002', '6103671', '6103673', '6103675'))
df_variants$variant_type <- factor(df_variants$variant_type, levels=c('INS', 'DEL'))
df_variants$approach <- factor(df_variants$approach, levels=c('reference', 'graph'))

### PLOT THE DATA
plot <- 
  ggplot(df_variants) +
  
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=sample, y=count, fill=variant_type), stat="identity", position="dodge", width=.3, alpha=.6) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(12, "Paired")[c(7, 8)], guide=guide_legend(title="variant type", ncol=2, title.position="top", title.hjust=.5)) + 
  
  new_scale_fill() +
  
  geom_bar(mapping=aes(x=sample, y=count*0, fill=approach), stat="identity", position="dodge", width=.3, alpha=.6) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(9, "Greys")[c(7, 3)], guide=guide_legend(title="approach", ncol=2, title.position="top", title.hjust=.5)) +
  
  theme_bw() + theme(plot.title=element_text(face='bold.italic', hjust=.5), legend.title=element_text(face='italic'), legend.position='bottom', legend.direction='horizontal') + 
  ggtitle("INDELs gain")
plot

ggsave(filename = "variants.png", width=6.5, height=5)
```